# Heroku: How do you push to specific app if you have multiple apps in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I create a new heroku app using `heroku create test-app3`. Now if I want to push some code to this new `test-app3`, how do I do that?

When I type `heroku list` in the terminal I get:
My Apps

- `test-app1`
- `test-app2`
- `test-app3`

How do I push to test-app3? How do I switch between which app to push to?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will need to setup different git remote end points for each application at Heroku so you can push to either application from the one local repo.

Get the GIT URLs for your apps on Heroku via the dashboard (it will look something similar to this: `https://git@heroku.com:your_app_name.git`) and do:

```
git remote add test-app1 https://git@heroku.com:test-app1.git

git remote add test-app2 https://git@heroku.com:test-app2.git

git remote add test-app3 https://git@heroku.com:test-app3.git
```

Then you will be able to push to any specific app like this:

```
git push test-app1 master

git push test-app2 master

git push test-app3 master
```

Comment: I was getting `fatal: Not a git repository ` so I typed `git init` but now if I type `git remote add test-app1` I get `usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>`. What should I do?

Comment: whats the output of your: `git remote -v`?

Comment: did you do this? `git remote add test-app1 <gitrepo for test-app1 here>`?
then should be able to see something when you do: `git remote -v`

Comment: gitrepo, I didn't do that. I don't have github so where do I get the `gitrepo`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90760/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-jamesrocky).

Comment: You need the `https://` before the git URL, so the correct URL is `https://git@heroku.com:test-app3.git`. I updated the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You navigate your app from terminal with `cd test-app3`, then:

```
git add .
git commit -m "your message"
git push
```

and finally:

`git push heroku master` or
`git push heroku main`, depending on the name of your main branch.