# Heroku - push subtrees to different apps

Tags: heroku

I have a two-part app (a Phoenix API and a React front-end) that I want to deploy to Heroku... the back-end and front-end need to run on separate servers, but the current app structure is like so:

```
app/
  |
  + Phoenix/
  |
  + React/
  |
  + .git/
```

So both parts of the app are in the same git repo.

Within `app/`, I created two different Heroku apps - I'll call them `phoenix-heroku-app` and `react-heroku-app`.  My plan is to use the git subtree method to push these apps up to Heroku, but I'm not sure how to specify where each should go.

When I run `heroku apps`, this correctly lists

```
phoenix-heroku-app
react-heroku-app
```

So they're both there... but when I use a command like

```
$ git subtree push --prefix Phoenix heroku master
$ git subtree push --prefix React heroku master
```

what is the syntax to point each of these pushes toward the correct app?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815483/heroku-how-do-you-push-to-specific-app-if-you-have-multiple-apps-in-heroku help at all? It looks from that like you could set up two different remotes, so instead of pushing to `heroku` you'd push to one remote for the Phoenix app and another for the React app.

Comment: @bouteillebleu great, thanks for pointing that out. I was able to use that tip to sort this out, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @bouteillebleu's suggestion, I was able to handle this like so...

First, I needed to add Heroku endpoints for the two apps in the parent directory -

```
$ git remote add phoenix-heroku-app https://git.heroku.com/phoenix-heroku-app.git
$ git remote add react-heroku-app https://git.heroku.com/react-heroku-app.git
```

Then I just needed to run

```
$ git subtree push --prefix Phoenix phoenix-heroku-app master
$ git subtree push --prefix React react-heroku-app master
```

and it was good to go.