# Why this git is not pushed properly to Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku

I have a folder (let's call it `Code1`) on my local machine which contains a php script, a README file and composer.json . I have created an app (let's call it `App1`) on Heroku by pushing this file to it. 
Now I want to create a new app with the same folder slightly modified.

For this reason, I copied and pasted the folder (let's call the new folder `Code2`) in my local machine.
Then I did the following things:

- Logged in Heroku at the terminal
- Entered the folder directory by entering `cd Code2`
- Entered `heroku create` (a new app was created - let's call it `App2`)
- Entered `git push heroku master`

The output I get after this is: `Everything up-to-date`

which essentially refers to `App1` and it does not then deploy `App2`.

How can I deploy `App2` by pushing my new folder (`Code2`) to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copied the `Code1` directory to `Code2`, you most likely copied the `.git` directory in `Code1`. Inside the file `.git/config` will be the heroku remote definition:

```
[remote "heroku"]
    url = https://git.heroku.com/App1.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

Since that remote definition points to `App1`, that's where `git push heroku master` pushes.

One way to update the heroku git remote to the new app would be to run the following command while you are in the `Code2` directory:

```
heroku git:remote -a App2
```

Comment: Nice one! I could also use this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815483/heroku-how-do-you-push-to-specific-app-if-you-have-multiple-apps-in-heroku/32815562#32815562 but essentially your solution is more precisely on my problem.